# How to remove numbering in theorem using mdframed package

Tags: numbering, mdframed

I want to remove numbering in this theorem defined in mdframed

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newcounter{theo}%[section] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!60!brown!60!]
{\strut Theorem~\thePrte};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!60!brown!60!]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=10pt, linecolor=yellow!60!brown!60!,%
linewidth=2.3pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax, roundcorner=5pt
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[{\tiny Théorème des valeurs intermédiaires}]{}
Soit $f$ une fonction definie sur $\mathbb{R}$...
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Remove `\thetheo` and `\thePrte` ?

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be sure that code you post compiles unless you are asking for help with a compilation error.

`\the<counter name>` produces a typeset version of the LaTeX counter `<counter>`'s current value. Hence, removing these removes the numbers from the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        {\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!60!brown!60!]
          {\strut Theorem};}%
      },
    }
  }%
  {%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        {\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!60!brown!60!]
          {\strut Theorem:~#1};}%
      },
    }%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{%
    innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=10pt, linecolor=yellow!60!brown!60!, linewidth=2.3pt,topline=true, frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax, roundcorner=5pt,
  }%
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax
    \label{#2}%
  }{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[{\tiny Théorème des valeurs intermédiaires}]{}
  Soit $f$ une fonction definie sur $\mathbb{R}$...
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image: numberless thm]

Comment: Thanks you for the help! I didn't used an appropriate package for accented letters, that's why it doesn't compile !

Comment: It doesn't compile because `\mathbb` is undefined without `amssymb`.